# Unable to read and convert the text file into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to read the image content using tesseract-OCR and write it into a text file in python.

now I am trying to read the content from the text file and convert it into the data frame

[sample text file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR1hy.jpg)

Here is my code to convert the text file into data frame:

```
filepath=r"D:\Projects\textfiles\outputfiles.txt"
chat_df = pd.read_csv(filepath,header=None,encoding='cp1252')
```

Comment: Why are you using read_csv on a file that is obviously not a CSV file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to extract the chat messages from teams  for  analysis. Chat Messages are stored in a image format, I have extracted the messages using tesseract ocr  in a  text file. I need to transform this into a data frame with columns such as {sender name, sender_timestamp, messages from sender}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd need to read the text file line by line and create a Pandas data frame from those lines before you can output a CSV file.

```
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()


        data = [line.strip().split() for line in lines]


        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What is this? Did you look at the sample input file?

Comment: Thank you DarkKnight, , it is working fine. but I want to transform  the messages also in to the previous row.

Comment: These are Chat messages, with  Sender name and time stamp in the 1st line and the senders messages in the next lines. i am not able  to transform these into a data frame